# How to use apache spark to face detection in video stream

Tags: apache-spark, video, spark-streaming

Here is the background of the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a video file (MPEG-2 encoded) sitting on some remote server.

My job is to write a program to conduct the face detection on this video file. The output is the collection of frames on which the face(s) detected. The frames are saved as JPEG files.

My current thinking is like this:

1. Using a HTTP client to download the remote video file;
2. For each chunk of video data being downloaded, I split it on the GOP boundary; so the output of this step is gonna be a video segment that contains one or more GOPs;
3. Create a RDD for each video segment aligned on the GOP boundary;
4. Transform each RDD into a collection of frames;
5. For each frame, run face detection;
6. if the face is detected, mark it and save the frame to JPEG file

**My question is:** Is *Apache-Spark* the right tool for this kind of work? If so, could someone point me to some example does the similar thing?